# Gutenberg: Restrict Top Level Blocks, But Not Child Blocks

Tags: block-editor

## Background

I've created a custom top level "page section" block, to work with my existing theme. I've like to restrict top level blocks to ONLY that one block. However, I don't want to disable all blocks completely, because I want all blocks available to use as innerBlocks.

## Question

How can I restrict top level blocks, without restricting child level blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can’t. But you can accomplish this by using a block template that only contains your block and is locked. If your block has an InnerBlocks instance, you can add any of the registered blocks to it.

```
add_action( 'init', 'insert_template' );
function insert_template() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
    $post_type_object->template =[ [ 'your-custom-block-name'] ];
    $post_type_object->template_lock = 'all';
}
```

Comment: I did a quick search and that may be exactly what I need. I'll investigate it further today.

Comment: I’ll try and get some code samples together and update my answer.

Comment: I added a bounty to this same question over on StackOverflow. If you'd like to post this answer there, I'll give you the bounty. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55962177/2111901

Comment: And I think what I need is two levels. A custom block called page body, or something, that is called in the template and locked. Then that has an innerBlocks locked to only my page section blocks, but unlimited. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I posted to the bounty as well

Comment: this does not seem to work anymore. can someone confirm this? (can not add sub level blocks like paaragraphs / headings. Works only as fixed template, or not at all)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom script to the admin panel using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

Here is an example of how you can restrict existing blocks to only be included inside certain blocks:

```js
const restrictEditorParentBlocks = (settings, name) => {
    const TEXT_EDITOR_BLOCKS = [
        'core/heading',
        'core/image',
        'core/list',
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/shortcode',
        'core/embed',
    ];

    if (TEXT_EDITOR_BLOCKS.includes(name)) {
        settings.parent = ['example/my-custom-block-that-needs-text-editor-blocks']
    }

    console.log(settings, name)

    return settings
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'your-project-name/restrict-parent-blocks',
    restrictEditorParentBlocks
);
```

This will disable them for the page, but allow them inside the specified parent blocks.

(see `settings.parent` assignment)